# How to get data from url in django without query parameters

Tags: django, get

sorry for my noob question as I am just starting to learn Django. I would appreciate if someone could tell me how can i change data dynamically on page in django. Let me clear this:

**What I want:**

When url is `http://localhost/data/1111`, page data should be like `data is 1111`.

When url is `http://localhost/data/2222`, page data should be like `data is 2222`.

**What I did:**

```
def index(request):
    print(int(request.GET["data"]))          # for debugging only
    return HttpResponse("data of Page")
```

and url was:

```
path('<int:data>', views.index, name='index')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a value in your url, the `<int:data>` part, that needs to be captured by the view, which means your view function has to be aware of the extra parameter.

So, the correct view for this would be:

```
def index(request, data):
    print(data)  # data is already converted to int, since thats what you used in your url
    return HttpResponse(f"data is {data}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to pass query parameters in your url, change your url to look like this

```
path('data/', views.index, name='index')

def index(request):
   print(int(request.GET["data"])) # for debugging only
   return HttpResponse("data of Page")
```

Note that on `GET['data']`, `data` is not what is on the url pattern but rather it should be a input name on the form like `<input name='amount' type='number' />`

Now you can access amount like this

```
def index(request):
   print(int(request.GET["amount"])) # for debugging only
   return HttpResponse("data of Page")
```